# How to dynamically change themes after clicking a drop down menu of themes with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]I'm using bootstrap for the interface of the website I'm developing. I am also planning to integrate the bootswatch themes to my site. I have created a dropdown menu containing the different themes of bootswatch. My problem is how can I switch themes when I click one of the themes in the dropdown menu?
Note that I want to do this with raw JavaScript without any special framework

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: The question is great. But you need to explain specifically in code what you want to solve. There are hundreds of examples on how to do this. What is your doubt? Please, be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Set your link with an id:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" id="dynamicCSS" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css" />
```

Apply an `onchange` event to your select list:

```html
<select id="myDropdownList" onchange="swapCSS()">
  <option>mystyle1.css</option>
  <option>mystyle2.css</option>
  <option>mystyle3.css</option>
</select>
```

Add your Javascript function:

```js
const swapCSS = function()
{
  let selection = document.getElementById("myDropdownList").selectedOptions[0];
  document.getElementById("dynamicCSS").href = selection.value;
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me, but it was not my answer thank you